# How to deal with missing values in K-means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working on customer segmentation based on their purchases for different type of product category.
Below is a dummy representation of my data. (The data is in percentage of the total revenue per each category the customer purchased):

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76atg.png)

As seen in the image link above, altho this data have only a few 0's but the original data has many 0s. therefore, using this data for kmeans clustering does not output any acceptable insights and skews the data towards the left.
dropping the rows or averaging the missing data is misleading. :/

Answer (score 0):

How to deal with missing values it's your choice, it will impact your clustering of course. There is no one "correct" way.
Few popular ways:

1. Fill each column missing values with average/mean of that feature
2. Bootstrapping: select random row and copy it's value to fill missing value
3. Closer Neighbor: find the closest neighbor and fill according to his missing values.

Without seeing your full data and why you're trying to do with clustering, it's a bit hard to help. Depends on the case...

You can always do some feature extraction (e.g. PCA), maybe it will give some better insights